# Fetch values in Target sheet from Source sheet based on the unique ID

Tags: excel, vba

There are two sheets - Source and Target. There is a unique ID in both sheets in Column-A.

In TargetSheet based on the uniqueID (Column-A), I want to fetch values from SourceSheet(Column-B) to TargetSheet(Column-B).

There are unique IDs in TargetSheet(Column-A) which are not in SourceSheet(Column-A), hence they should be left blank.

```
Sub Recon()
    
    Dim lrow, i, j As Long
    lrow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    TargetSheet.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    
    j = 1
    
    For i = 3 To lrow
   
        Do
            j = j + 1
            If Range("A" & i) = SourceSheet.Range("A" & j) Then
                Cells(i, 2) = SourceSheet.Range("B" & j).Value
            End If
        Loop Until Range("A" & i) = SourceSheet.Range("A" & j)
            
    Next i
       
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you would be better off using MSAccess instead of Excel. It does all that and more, automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it combining VLOOKUP trapped into an IFERROR to handle missing ids. VLOOKUP will look a value in a column and if found, will return a value **in same row** but different custom column. If there is no coincidence, it will raise an error, so we combine it with IFERROR to transform that error into blank value, which means that id is not found.

> **[VLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)**
>
> **[IFERROR function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)**

My fake data is just 2 sheets like yours:

[image]

The code I've used:

```
Sub test()

Dim WKsource As Worksheet
Dim WKTarget As Worksheet
Dim UF As Long

Set WKsource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceSheet")
Set WKTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TargetSheet")

With WKTarget
    UF = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B2:B" & UF).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & WKsource.Name & "!C1:C2,2,FALSE),"""")" 'get values
    .Range("B2:B" & UF) = .Range("B2:B" & UF).Value 'paste formula results as values
End With

Set WKTarget = Nothing
Set WKsource = Nothing

End Sub
```

My final output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, It looks great but request you to help me achieve that output with code which has Loops and Conditions only. The development team assign this task to me and  they don't want me to use vlookup or index-match.

Comment: *they don't want me to use vlookup or index-match* Why? O_o

Comment: I think they want to use the logic on other huge data sets, wherein they feel vlookup is less reliable... Can you do a logic without lookup or index-match ? if you see my code its almost there, however its not working on different IDs which are not there in SourceSheet

Comment: Look at `Find` and `FindNext` rather than using loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Sub Test()

```
Dim Source As Range
Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source").Range("A2:A5")

Dim Target As Range
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Target").Range("A2:A6")

Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
For Each TargetCell In Target
    Set FoundCell = Source.Find(TargetCell.Value, _
                                Source.Cells(1, 1), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        TargetCell.Offset(, 1) = FoundCell.Offset(, 1)
    End If

Next TargetCell
```

End Sub`